# How nginx pick the configuration order?

Tags: nginx

In my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file I have config. as:-

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Now, I don't like to pollute above default nginx.conf file, so I kept configuration in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf as:-

```
worker_processes 2;
events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}
```

My question is, In above scenario will nginx override or pick configuration for worker_processes and worker_connections from default.conf file or nginx.conf file ? Also, I would like to know how nginx processes configuration files in short ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "how nginx processes configuration files", a simple way to look at it would be:

- reading of configuration starts with `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
- directives are read from top to bottom
- `include`ing a file inserts it at the location of the `include`
  similar to the way the C preprocessor does
- a setting has a scope, such as `http`, `server`, or `location`, in order from wide to narrow
- some settings can occur at multiple scope levels
- setting a parameter at a narrower scope overrides a setting of the same parameter at a wider scope
- conflicting settings within the same scope are rejected

For detail, see the Debian wiki article on Nginx directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure that configuration in default.conf will be picked first by nginx, thats why the line "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;" is included to override any defaults and add functionality.